# CSS card movement transition

Tags: css, typescript, next.js

Tech Stack: NextJS, TypeScript, CSS

I am working on my personal portfolio site where I decided to made cards to depict different skills. I came up with a cool idea to animate them. As shown below in the image, I want those arrows to function like whenever user clicks left arrow the card on the left disappers and the card on the right comes to the left and on the right-hand side a new card comes.

[image]

Let's assume I am fetching the details for cards from an API, I created or it is statically stored in an array.

I came up with an idea to just use double pointers on an array, where I can just increase/decrease the pointer based on the arrows clicked.

I am just curious how can I achieve the smooth animation/transition to do so.

**Container.tsx**

```
export default function Container() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.card_container}>
            <a href="#"><Image className={styles.arrows} src="/imgs/arrow-left.png" alt="This is just a left arrow" width={40} height={40} /></a>
            {
                cards.map((card: Card) => (
                    <CardContainer key={`${card.title}-${card.emoji}`}
                        backgroundColor={card.backgroundColor}
                        title={card.title}
                        emoji={card.emoji}
                        text={card.text}
                    />
                ))
            }
            <a href="#" ><Image className={styles.arrows} src="/imgs/arrow-right.png" alt="This is just a right arrow" width={40} height={40} /></a>
        </div>
    );
}

function CardContainer({ backgroundColor, title, emoji, text}: {backgroundColor: string, title: string, emoji: string, text: string}) {
    return(
        <div className={styles.card} style={{ backgroundColor }}>
            <h2 className={styles.card_title}>{title} {emoji}</h2>
            <p className={styles.card_text}>{text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am still figuring it out how can I achieve such smooth transition. I came up with the logic of double pointers.

Comment: Can you make an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?